# Javascript color game

Tags: javascript

I've looked all over the internet for a solution, but I am not sure why this won't show up in the browser. It works in a repl for javascript, but it won't open in my google browser for some reason.

```html
<script>function numbergame() {
 colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Indigo", "Violet", "Gray", "Black", "White"]
 var random_color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*colors.length)]
 var guesses = 0;
 var thecolor = false;
 var playerguess;
 while (!thenumber) {
 playerguess = prompt("I am thinking of a number color from this list:\n" +color +"\nCan you guess which one it is?");
 guesses+=1;
 thenumber = checkguess()
};

function checkguess() {

  if (!colors.include(playerguess)) {alert("Please enter a valid color"); return false}
  if (playerguess<random_color) {alert("Hint: the answer is lower alphabetically.");return false}
  if (playerguess>random_color) {alert("Hint: the answer is higher alphabetically.");return false}
  else {alert("You've guessed the color! It was " + random_number+" and it took you " + guesses+ " tries.");
  myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  myBody.style.background=thecolor;
  return true;}
}</script>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 Color Game.
</head>
<body onload= "numbergame()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you're missing a closing curly brace after the while loop in the numbergame function

Comment: The code is horribly broken. There's missing braces, variable scope issues, undefined variables. Awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closing brace to match the one on the line:

```
while (!thenumber) {
```

Using proper indentation and formatting will make errors like this one easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is not valid HTML.

Your `<script>` tag must be placed either in the `<body>` or the `<head>` of the HTML document, not in the very beginning, before the doctype.

Comment: Putting a `<script>` tag outside the document is technically invalid, but will run in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

So many issues with this HTML file. I've corrected the issues, but it's still pretty badly coded, even when fixed. However, here it is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
'use strict';
function numbergame() {
    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Indigo", "Violet", "Gray", "Black", "White"];
    var random_color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    var guesses = 0;
    var thecolor = false;
    var playerguess;
    var thenumber = false;
    while (!thenumber) {
        playerguess = prompt("I am thinking of a number color from this list:\n" + colors + "\nCan you guess which one it is?");
        guesses += 1;
        thenumber = checkguess(colors, playerguess, random_color, guesses);
    }
};

function checkguess(colors, playerguess, random_color, guesses) {
        if (!colors.includes(playerguess)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid color"); return false
        }

        if (playerguess < random_color) {
            alert("Hint: the answer is lower alphabetically.");
            return false;
        }

        if (playerguess > random_color) {
            alert("Hint: the answer is higher alphabetically.");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("You've guessed the color! It was " + random_color + " and it took you " + guesses + " tries.");
            var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            myBody.style.background = random_color;
            return true;
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="numbergame()">
<h1>Color Game</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The issues were undeclared variables, missing curly braces, scope problems, `<script>` tags in wrong places, etc. You'd be better off coding this from scratch yourself to be honest.

I tested this on Firefox 47.0.1. You may encounter other browser compatibility issues, but I'm sure you can fix those for yourself from here :)

Answer (score -1):

the while loop in numbergame function should look like this:

```
while (!thenumber) {
    playerguess = prompt("I am thinking of a number color from this list:\n" +color +"\nCan you guess which one it is?");
    guesses+=1;
    thenumber = checkguess();
} // <-- this curly brace was missing
```